# how to pass value to two views from a function in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-routing

I have a problem that has the same situation I need to pass an individual student ID to ResultController and AttendenceController to get an indidual student Data  if the value is to only function it works but i want to pass the value to two diffrent controller and two diffrent views (i am using bootstrap nav tab) where i need index page should pass student id of student to result and attendence controller and the tab should show indvidual student attendence and result

```
 public function getStudent($id)
{
  
  
   $bens = Attendence::where('student_id',$id)->paginate(6);
 return view('atten.index',compact('bens','id'))->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

here is the route function which we need to pass from the index page

```
Route::get('/atten/getStudent/{id}', 
    ['uses' => 'AttendenceController@getStudent', 'as' => 'getStudent']);
```

from one click it should pass id to result controller and attendence controller how to do it , i dont like to use  boot()method in AppServiceProvider is it poassible to solve the problem with another method. thanks

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Comment: thank you @FluxCoder i am using laravel-8

Comment: Sounds impossible, you can only address one controller&method in a route. Save in a session and use it in the other controller

Comment: @brombeer if i save the data into Session it only accessible inside one controller cannot use another controller, do you have any other solution . thanks

Answer (score 0):

First I group the routes in middleware and then use Session()->put Method while getting Student ID then I can use in any route which is a group in Middleware by using session()->get('');